# Regex to find file version C#

Tags: regex, file, version, regex-group

Below are some examples of the file name without extension, from which I want to extract version and type of the file.

1] 2.13.1801.221     **Expected output**-`[Version: 2.13.1801.221  and Type: Null]`

2] 2.17.1801.221.SQLServer
     **Expected output**-`[Version: 2.17.1801.221  and Type: SQLServer]`

3] 2.19.1801.SQLite
   **Expected output**-`[Version: 2.19.1801  and Type: SQLite]`

I am using below regex to extract version and type from file name

`^(?<version>(\d+\.\d+)+)\.(?<type>\w*)$`

But this doesn't work.

Tested with regex online which shows result as:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9FlW.png]

Match groups formed as: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0azi.png
]

What am I missing here ? 
please suggest some good regex.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is a little incorrect which is why it is not working. The correct regex you should use is following,

```
^(?<version>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)(?:\.(?<type>[a-zA-Z]+))?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nuiE6V/1)**

Here is the explanation of problems in your `^(?<version>(\d+\.\d+)+)\.(?<type>\w*)$` regex,

- This `(\d+\.\d+)+` in your regex will not correctly capture version as this will expect data of type one or more digits followed by literal dot again followed by one or more digits and whole it it one or more times. The corrected version of this part will be this `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` which can capture strings like `1.1` or `1.2.33.11` etc.
- Second problem in your regex part is this `\.(?<type>\w*)` where this will match a literal dot and then zero or more word character which will even match last digit part in case there is actually no version data due to which it will match `221` in string `2.13.1801.221` which is not what you want. In fact since your version can be absent in the string, you need to use `?` operator to specify the whole group as being optional and use `[a-zA-Z]` for capturing version data and your corrected regex part should be this `(?:\.(?<type>[a-zA-Z]+))?`. In case your version data can contain numbers, then you can enhance your second by making changing `[a-zA-Z]+` to `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*` where it means your version string should start with alphabet and numbers can be present later.
- Also, I have made some groups in your regex as non-capture groups by placing `?:` just before `(` as you don't need to capture them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are always assuming that there would be `.` after the version numbers. However, if there is no type specified after the version, the extra `.` would not exist. So instead, you could use the following:

```
^(?<version>[\d+\.]+\d)\.*(?<type>\w*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ek6Zfd/1)

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- The version capture group is defined by `(?<version>[\d+\.]+\d)`

  - `[\d+\.]+` matches 1+ number of digit following by `.` for 1+ number of times
  - `\d` matches the last digit
- `\.*` matches whether there is any type specified after the version numbers
- The type capture group is defined by `(?<type>\w*)`

  - `\w*` matches any number of word characters
- `$` matches the end of the line